# Existence of generic points for a dynamical system

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $M$ be a compact space (not necessarily Hausdorff), $T:M\rightarrow M$ continuous bijective and $\mu$ an ergodic $T$-invariant probabilistic measure on $M$. A point $x\in M$ is ***generic*** if 
$$\mu=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \delta_{T^{k}(x)}$$
(here $\delta_x$ denotes the Dirac measure on $x$). Now, I want to know if there exists a generic point $x\in M$.

I know that this result is true when $M$ is a *compact metric space* just assuming that $T$ is measurable. Essentially, this is a consequence of Birkhoff's ergodic theorem and Stone–Weierstrass theorem. However, for a compact space I cannot always use the latter theorem.

Comment: Note that the Stone--Weierstrass theorem can be extended to locally compact Hausdorff spaces for the continuous functions vanishing at infinity.   So generic points should always exist (under your assumptions) for locally compact separable spaces. At present I don't see any change in the proof.

Comment: You are right in your comment . In fact, on the literature the existence of generic point requires that $C(M)$ (the spaces of continuous function on $M$) is separable. In this case, I’m trying to deduce the existence only assuming that $M$ is compact ($C(M)$ is not necessarily separable) and giving stronger assumptions  on $T$ (bijective+continuity).

Comment: My point was more that the set of continuous functions vanishing at infinity for a general *locally compact separable Hausdorff space* is separable. So I believe that you can repeat the usual proof to construct a generic point, even showing as an additional result that the set of measures is metrizable.

Comment: @JohnB That's only true if you assume at that $M$ is metrizable. Take for example $M = \{0, 1\}^{\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})}$ with the product topology. Then for every $S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, consider the continuous function $f_S(x) = x_S$, i.e. the function that reads the value of $x$ at $S$. Then $S \mapsto f_S$ is an injective mapping $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to C(M)$, meaning $|C(M)| > |\mathbb{R}|$. But a separable space has cardinality at most $|\mathbb{R}|$.